# What's happening in this constructor and destructor?

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor

since many years I have to come back to use c++. I'm a bit rusty, can someone please explain me what is happening when contructing and deconsturcting the object in the main function.

The code is working as intendet. Strange is, that if I debug the code the debugger stops the execution  two times, when constructing the class and 3 times when destroying. But it stops in a part of code, where is no debug-Information is awaylable (yes gcc is generating me debug info). I wanted to investigate that, but I am not really sure what the code really does.

Here's the Code:

```
class LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice;

class LSPI_BusSymulation{
public:
    LSPI_BusSymulation(uint16_t dataSizePerDevice, uint16_t maxNumberOfDevices, uint16_t actualNumberOfDevices);
private:
    uint16_t actualNumberOfDevices;
    std::vector<LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice> devices;
    std::vector<uint8_t> recvData;
};

class LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice{
public:
    LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice(uint16_t processDataSizePerDevice, uint16_t maxNumberOfDevices);
private:
    uint16_t dataSizePerDevice;
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
};

LSPI_BusSymulation::LSPI_BusSymulation(uint16_t dataSizePerDevice, uint16_t maxNumberOfDevices, uint16_t actualNumberOfDevices)
    : actualNumberOfDevices(actualNumberOfDevices){    
    recvData.resize(dataSizePerDevice * (maxNumberOfDevices + 1));
    devices.assign(actualNumberOfDevices, LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice(dataSizePerDevice, maxNumberOfDevices));
}

LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice::LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice(uint16_t processDataSizePerDevice, uint16_t maxNumberOfDevices)
    : dataSizePerDevice(processDataSizePerDevice){
    data.resize(processDataSizePerDevice * (maxNumberOfDevices + 1 + 1));
}

int main(){    
    LSPI_BusSymulation busSymulation(10, 10, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Importantant questions for me are: (But if you have time a step by step explanaiton would also help)

How often will the constructor and destructor of LSPI_SYMULATION_SLAVE_DEVICE get called?

Are all objects stored in busSymulation.devices seperate objects with their own memory?

Is the vector busSymulation.devices[n].data also copied or do the devices share one data-vector?

Comment: Perhaps you need to read what [.resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) and [.assign](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/assign/) do?

Comment: @freakish sure I did that. But i'm not sure if I understood it correctly.For Assign: I think, that one const object is assigned. This object is then copied multiple times. So constructor is called once. When this vector is deleted the obecjts destructor is called vector.size() + 1 times. But I am not really sure. Everything works well, but the debugger is behaving oddly what makes me think I understood something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> How often will the constructor and destructor of
>   LSPI_SYMULATION_SLAVE_DEVICE get called?

The constructor

```
LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice::LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice(uint16_t processDataSizePerDevice, uint16_t maxNumberOfDevices)
```

is called once. Copy constructor is called 10 times. Desctructor is called 11 times.

> Are all objects stored in busSymulation.devices seperate objects with their own memory?

Yes

> Is the vector busSymulation.devices[n].data also copied or do the devices share one data-vector?

It's copied.